# Extracting year from date and using the year to fetch data from DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

First of all i'd like to say that i am fairly new to the programming world. 
I am creating a system where Date plays a major role, I am currently able to display all the items where full date is shown, however i would like to create a menu where the user can view his transactions by month and year.

```
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Transaction Date</th><th>Total Amount</th></tr>"; 

    $val=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT TransactionDate, SUM(Amount) FROM                   transaction GROUP BY TransactionDate");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($val))
    { 
        echo ("

        <tr><td><a href='inserttransaction.php?date=$row[0]'>$row[0]</a></td>
        <td>$row[1]</td></tr>");

    }
```

With the help of the above code i was able to group them all by using the current date, I'm quite new to the programming world and need help or clues on how do i make it year wise or say month wise. How am i supposed to extract only the "year" from it and as i am gonna go and display all the items saved in the DB with the current YEAR, how do i extract those items through the DB?

Comment: what is your date format?usually in db date format is stored in yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Use `YEAR(TransactionDate)` in your query

Comment: @user3386779 its yyyy/mm/dd only.

Comment: that's  you need to extract yyyy from date rite?

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Something like for yearly grouping:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(TransactionDate, "%Y") as date_key, 
       SUM(Amount) 
 FROM transaction 
GROUP BY date_key;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.first fetch the date from db and move it to variable.To know the date format [Manual click here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

```
$datz=$row['date'];
$time=strtotime($dateValue);
$month=date("F",$time);
$year=date("Y",$time);
```

Comment: you can also done this by suggestion given by @KiwiJuicer